Google Apps Script triggered via a trigger doesn't run anymore
since a couple of weeks I see that my functions triggered via a time-based trigger and not running successfully anymore.
The trigger starts the script.
The function is also executed for roughly 1 sec. Normal duration of the functions is >100 sec.
In the logs you can't find any error message or similar and the the function is marked as "finished".
Anyone has an idea or stumbled about something similar?

Please add more details, like the type of triggers what the triggers does, what Services it uses, the type of account uses to create the triggers, etc.

@Wicket thanks for your reply. Could you give more hints, what you are missing?
As stated it's a time-based trigger, which triggers another function of my script. It doesn't use any special services and if I run the function on its own. Everything works.

I edited my previouss comment

Are there try catch blocks?

FloW, does your case is related to any of this issues?
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36763131
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36755530

By default, triggers are set to send emails with a list of errors once a day. Look at the account's email inbox that created this trigger for failure notification email.
For debugging purposes, change the trigger error email frequency to Immediately. This should be done using the Google Apps Script user interface.
Also, you might consider creating a standard Google Cloud project and linking it to your Google Apps Script project to use more advanced logging features. An alternative is to use a spreadsheet for logging. If you go for this option, you might want to look to BetterLog. This is a GitHub repository with instructions on how to use an open-source Google Apps Script library to extend the logging features.
Related

Can Trigger notifications to "immediately" be done programmatically?

